# If multiple cells value match return value from master cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am currently working on an invoicing spreadsheet for our furniture delivery business. I am having trouble with linking multiple cells to a master cell.
For Example, if we deliver a table to a customer we would charge for the table delivery by size, but for tracking purposes on our delivery application we track the individual boxes the table is packaged in.

- *Master Code:* Oak_Dining_Table
- *Sub-Code:* Oak_Dining_Table_**-_Top**
- *Sub-Code:* Oak_DIning_Table_**-_Legs**

We require to find the Master Code volume(CBM) if all components linked to the master are detected. How would go about create a formula?

[image: Spreadsheet Data Example]

[image]

Comment: Can you show us what you have done so far and explain what the problem you encountered is?

Comment: @Edward - I know you mentioned adapting question/my soln being helpful; I had a dispute with one of the editors that made me feel like I wasted an awful amount of my time; so feeling down-trodden about this - have removed my soln altogether hope you captured what you needed to.  It's pity when potential mis-comms results in silly quarrels.  If you need it back up let me konw I'll undelete temporarily.  ta